# How to do batched transactions in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

After a few searches, it appears that it is impossible to run batched transactions.

What I want to achieve:

- I have an app that tracks transactions.
- I need to display both the monthly and overall spending/earnings, so I need to keep a tally of them.
- What this means is that I need to run 3 operations simultaniusly: add the transaction to the `transaction` collection, update the overall tally and update the monthly tally

How do I update both the overall and monthly spending/earnings to keep consistency?

Is there really no way of running batched transactions? If so, what's the next best solution?

Comment: [Transactions and Batches Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#web-version-9)

Comment: This sounds like cloud function triggered onWrite to the transaction collection.  See here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Comment: Given the documentation about transactions in the link provided by the first comment, what exactly is impossible about what you're trying to do?  Is there some limitation in the system that you're trying to overcome? Do you have any code that you've tried that doesn't work the way you expect?  It's hard to know what sort of answer you're looking for.

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah, so I'm looking for a solution where I can write a new document, and update two already existing ones (with transactions), but if one operation fails I need every operation to change.

Comment: If you have code that fails, you should include that in your question to so we can see what you might be doing wrong. You'll get help much faster that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to run 3 operations simultaniusly: add the transaction to the
> transaction collection, update the overall tally and update the
> monthly tally

As Tim mentioned in his comment you need to use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) since you want to first read the monthly and total docs before updating them (and create the transaction doc) in an atomic manner.

Something along the following lines:

```
import { runTransaction } from "firebase/firestore";

try {
    const newTransactionDocRef = ...;
    const amount = ...,
    const monthlyDocRef = ...;
    const totalDocRef = ...;
    await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
        const monthlyDoc = await transaction.get(monthlyDocRef);
        const totalDoc = await transaction.get(totalDocRef);
        
        transaction.set(newTransactionDocRef, {...});
        const newMonthlyTally = monthlyDoc.data().total + amount;
        transaction.update(monthlyDocRef, { total: newMonthlyTally });
        const newTotalTally = totalDoc.data().total + amount;
        transaction.update(totalDocRef, { total: newTotalTally });
    });
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
}
```

Note  that you need to initiate the monthly and total docs.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one question though, what happens if right after I read the value of `monthly spending` it gets updated by something else, and then when the transaction completes it updates based on the outdated values?

Comment: As explained in the doc: "In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire transaction again." Avoiding "updates based on outdated values" is exactly the goal of a Transaction. More detailed explanations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention) in the doc.

Comment: And if I understand correctly if one operation fails (of the 3) the whole transaction fails? And "concurrent edit" means if any of the read values change the transaction also fails. And if it fails does it retries automatically?

Comment: Thank you, you helped a lot! I was having a lot of trouble figuring this one out alone :) - as soon as I get it to work, I'll accept your answer, and thanks again!

Comment: #1Yes. #2 The transaction is retried and takes the new values (However "If the transaction can't get a clean result after a few retries, the transaction fails due to data contention." see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#data_contention_in_the_mobileweb_sdks)) #3 It depends on the reason of failure: if it fails because any document did change, the transaction handler retries the transaction. If it is another non recoverable error (e.g. non-existing doc to be updated it definitely fails)

Comment: I see. And how can I handle that specific situation when it fails to many times due to changing values?

Comment: As explained in the same doc: "After a finite number of retries, the transaction operation fails and returns an error message: ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents. Please try again."

Comment: Hey! It was a long run to successfully scale up your solution to fit my problem but I was able to, so I accepted your answer! Thanks again!